# Access URL parameters in Angularjs in the Controller

Tags: angularjs, parameters, request

How to access the URL parameters through the angularJS controller. For example: i would like to read parameter1 and parameter2 in a controller so that i can take appropriate action in my controller.  http://localhost:8080/MyApplication?Parameter1=testresponse&parameter2=1234

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After spending some time, i figured that $location is the one I was searching for.  Below is sample code snippet. >>AngularJS v1.4.8

**main.js**

```
     var mainApp = angular.module("app",['ui.bootstrap','ngModal']);
    mainApp.config(['$locationProvider',function($locationProvider){    
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });

    var mainController = function($scope,$window,$rootScope, $cookies,$cookieStore,$location){
var searchObject = $location.search();

    window.alert("parameter is :.."+searchObject.param1);
    window.alert("Url typed in the browser is: "+$location.absUrl());
    }

    mainApp.controller("MainController",["$scope","$window","$rootScope",'$location',mainController]);
```

**Enter the this URL in the browser:**
http://localhost:8180/Application/#param1=test

**Output:**

alert 1: parameter is :.. test

alert 2: "Url typed in the browser is: " +http://localhost:8180/Application/#param1=test

Comment: Appreciated it !! Self Explored Great !! Barani !!

Answer (score 1):

Inject $routeParams in your controller like

```
angular.module(yourapp).controller(yourcontroller,['$routeParams',
function($routeParams){
    console.log($routeParams.Parameter1) //Prints test response
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `$routeParams` service you can access url params. In your case

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
 .controller('myController', (function ($scope, $routeParams) {
   $routeParams.Parameter1 // for 1st param
   $routeParams.parameter2 // for second param
});
```

For more information - [$routeParams](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams)

Comment: Getting "Param...undefined" error  for angular.module('myApp', [])
 .controller('myController', (function ($scope, $routeParams) {
   window.alert("Param.."+$routeParams.Parameter1); // for 1st param
   $routeParams.parameter2 // for second param
});

Comment: please create a fiddle so we can reproduce your problem and fix it

Comment: i was looking for $location. Anyways...Thanks for your time.:)