# I want to show student details by passing student id via routing in angularjs. But I am unable to do it

Tags: angularjs, routes

I am new to Angular JS and try to view student details by passing student id using routing

I have coded a bit but not geeting where to add the details of students and how to pass student id

```
this is the code for index.html
```

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#add"> Add Student </a></li>
                <li><a href="#show"> Show Student </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div >
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

````````````````````````````````````````````
this is the code for app.js
```````````````````````````````````````````
var myApp = angular.module('stuApp', []);
myApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/add', {
                templateUrl: 'add_student.html',
                controller: 'addCtrl'
            }).
            when('/show', {
                templateUrl: 'show_student.html',
                controller: 'showCtrl'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/add'
            });
    }]);


myApp.controller('addCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.message = 'This is Add new Student screen';

});


myApp.controller('showCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.message = 'This is Show Student screen';

})
````````````````````````````````````````````

I want to add student details in via form but dont dont know how to add those values in controller

`````````````````````````````
add_student.html
````````````````````````````
<script type="text/ng-template" id="add_student.html">
<h2>Add New Student</h2>

{{ message }}
</script>
`````````````````````````````

show_student.html

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="show_student.html">
<h2>Show Order</h2>

{{ message }}
</script>

I want the output as to pass object in controller display the students name and by clicking on the name student details should be displayed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Akansha for pass the parameters through routing in the url you need to change your $routeProvider in something like that:

```
when('/add/:StudentId', {
            templateUrl: 'add_student.html',
            controller: 'addCtrl'
        })
```

This means that if your url is `/add/1837` the parameter StudentId would have the value 1837.

For get the value of StudenId in your controller you can use $routeParams.

So for example your controller could be like the following one:

```
 myApp.controller('showCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.message = 'This is Show Student screen';
    var studentId = $routeParams.StudentId;
 })
```

You can obtain more information from the following link [URL-Routing - GitHub](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing)

Also there are other ways of access the url parameters, they are described in the following SO questions [Access URL parameters in Angularjs in the Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36573129/access-url-parameters-in-angularjs-in-the-controller) and [How to get the url parameters using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11758079/how-to-get-the-url-parameters-using-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

In Your app.js route config code, add route param ID like below

```
       when('/show/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'show_student.html',
            controller: 'showCtrl'
        })
```

In your index.html, pass ID through `a` tag

```
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#add"> Add Student </a></li>
            <li><a href="#show/{{id}}"> Show Student </a></li>
        </ul>
```

And in show controller, inject `$routeParams` first,

```
myApp.controller('showCtrl', function ($scope,$routeParams) {
  $scope.studentID = $routeParams.id; //passsed ID
 $scope.message = 'This is Show Student screen';
})
//you can use student ID to  filter your data in showStudent.html
```